# How to call C++(20) module from C#?

Tags: c#, c++20, c++-modules

bar.ixx

```
import <iostream>;

export module bar;

export void hello() {
    std::cout << "hello\n";
}
```

possible C# code

```
using bar;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bar.hello();
}
```

How to call bar module from C#?

Comment: I don't know that C++ modules change anything about how C++ interacts with C#. What are you seeing if you try to use your usual C# methods with a C++ DLL built from a module?

Comment: thanks @NicolBolas,change export to dllexport and add extern "C",C# side use dllimport works fine.